# Asymptotic analysis references

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, reference-request, asymptotics

I'm self studying asymptotic analysis with

- Bruijn (1981) - Asymptotic Methods in Analysis
- Bleistein and Handelsman (1986) - Asymptotic Expansions of Integrals

but the texts are terse, without too many examples, and the exercises don't have solutions. Could you please recommend texts on the same topic that are perhaps a bit easier and/or come with solutions for exercises? I'm reading these so that I can understand better Laplace transforms and saddlepoint methods. I took real analysis, functional analysis and complex analysis as an undergrad and can fill in some gaps if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using J.D. Murray's Asymptotic Analysis.

But it's not enough reading this book, he references Copson's book to complement his text in stuff that isn't proved in his text.

There are no solutions at the back, though.

But try asking your questions from the exercises here or in mathoverflow, I am sure you'll find someone who can help you.

Another good book (which I was reading it as a PDF) for Laplace transform theory (most books in control theory where you use Laplace transform don't go that much rigorous in the theory) is the book by M.G. Smith called Laplace transform theory. In this book there are worked out examples and exercises with answers but no detailed solutions.

Hope my answer helps you.

Comment: It no doubt will. +1 and thank you.